# kotlin - what is the better way than passing activity to non_activity classes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I've written some classes for making and using some tools in my app , for example I've written a class for making drawer navigation and I use it in some of my activities . for preventing over using the same code, I've used a custom class and I just call it in my activity and pass the activity to it

this is my code :

```
class Drawer(_activity: Activity) :NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {
private val activity:Activity
private val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private val nav_view:NavigationView

init{
    activity=_activity
    drawerLayout=activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    nav_view=activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_nav_view)
}

fun makeDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.drawer_home -> {
            Log.v(Constants.TAG,"home clicked")
        }
    }
    closeDrawer()
    return true
}

fun closeDrawer()=drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)
```

is it a good way to pass activity to non-activity classes to prevent over using some codes ? is there any alternative for that ?

Comment: Although your current way is not bad rather than using classes i always prefer to use extension functions if a piece code is to be used multiple times in my application

Comment: Why not just pass `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView` as constructor parameters directly?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thansk for reply ,  I can do this , but is this a better way ?

Comment: Clearly a better way, because you can't really know if the Activity has those views or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing reference of activity leads to possible crashes.
There is a better way. You can create `DrawerActivity` that extends `AppCompatActivity` and put most of this logic into it.
Then when you have activity that uses drawer, you just extend `DrawerActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`.

Make few abstract functions like

```
abstract fun getDrawerLayout(): DrawerLayout
abstract fun getNavView(): NavView
```

That you will implement this methods in activity that extends your `DrawerActivity`.
This way you will have available all things that you need in you `DrawerActivity` to connect logic for drawer.

Your function

```
fun makeDrawer() {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}
```

would now be

```
fun makeDrawer() {
    getDrawer().openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)
    getNavView().setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
}
```

Other parts of class you can also replace.